# copy cell data and pasting into a variable(pasteSpecial)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to copy a cell content which is formula based

I want to copy this data to a variable as plain text. How do i do this

```
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Copy
COmp_Val =
```

I want to copy only the conet to this string variable COmp_Val

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the value property of the cell to a variable.

```
Dim s As String
s = ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value
```

In your case change `s` for your variable name.

Comment: I have one more situation but dont want to open a thread for that

Call Populate(Comp_Str, Comp_Val)

When I excicute the following it says ByRef Argument mismatch

CompStr and Comp_Val are string

and here is the sub defination
Sub Populate(Str As String, Tpry_Str As String)

Comment: If you declare the variables as String: `Dim Comp_Str, Comp_Val As String` it's musn't be any error because the cast type is automatic.  I you want to get a more clear code you can cast types manually: `Comp_Val = CStr(ActiveCell.Offset(0,1).Value)`